# Top-to-bottom mode for VS diff tool

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, diff

When I'm opening two files side-by-side, opening some diffs forces me to watch files in 1/4 width of working area and that's uncomfortable. Any way to change that behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

If you're asking how to change the diff from Side-by-side to Inline view, you can do that from the Compare Files toolbar:

[image: VS Compare Files toolbar showing view options]

Comment: It's close, but I'm talking about _vertical_ side-by-side.

Comment: @TrolltheLegacy so you want Side-by-side but in a vertical layout?  That's not a VS feature today, but you can send in a suggestion/feature request.  I could also see that being useful for people who orient their monitors in portrait mode instead of landscape.

Comment: Done https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/392411/vertical-layout-for-side-by-side-mode-of-comparer.html